# order of translation vs rotation in static_transform_publisher

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic, translation, static-transform-publisher, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am playing a rosbag containing pointclouds on kinetic.
I need to set the tf so that it is at a decent location to the [Panda robot](https://frankaemika.github.io/) for some task.

The following is the relevant line from my launch file that set the static transform

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="to_panda_base" args="0 0 2 0 0.2 1.92 camera_rgb_optical_frame panda_link0 100" />
```

When running the code like this (with translation and rotation given) the result is:

```
At time 1527473959.781
- Translation: [0.397, -1.842, 0.671]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.815, -0.057, 0.082, 0.571]
            in RPY (radian) [-1.914, 0.068, 0.188]
            in RPY (degree) [-109.640, 3.898, 10.784]
```

The issue is that if both rotation and translation are given which is applied first.
one of the comments [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/242605/relationship-between-tf-rotation-and-translation/) mentions that the translation takes place first.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292842/order-of-translation-vs-rotation-in-static_transform_publisher/) by [Ridhwanluthra](https://answers.ros.org/users/34902/ridhwanluthra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2018-05-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-31**:
What is weird about this exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is expected behavior, but I guess you wanted to see the same numbers and just accidentally printed the transform the wrong way around.

`rosrun tf tf_echo camera panda`
vs
`rosrun tf tf_echo panda camera`

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2018-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ridhwanluthra](https://answers.ros.org/users/34902/ridhwanluthra/) on 2018-06-02**:
Ya that was one of the issues. The major problem that I had was because I read in a comment on [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/242605/relationship-between-tf-rotation-and-translation/) that the translation is applied first and then the rotation takes place but that was not the case.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-06-04**:
Translation does take place first, where the parent frame is the first frame argument to static_transform_publisher (camera) and the child is the second (panda).  You can see the parent child relationship with `rostopic echo /tf`.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-06-04**:
Also use the tf plugin in rviz (set fixed frame to the parent), and perhaps experiment with splitting your transform into a translation and a rotation (with a new intermediate frame between them) and play with order that way and observe the results in rviz.